# Use grep to search text in each csv file on S3 bucket

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-s3

I am on AWS s3 bucket and there are hundreds of CSVs in the folder. I want to list (ie. ls) the name/s of the CSV file/s that contain the text/word that I am looking for.

`aws s3 ls  s3://path/folder/ | grep -l 'word' *.csv`

The command above returns this error.

`grep: *.csv: No such file or directory [Errno 32] Broken pipe Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Please let me know how I can rewrite it, so that it displays the file/s that contain the text/word.

Comment: Are you just looking for a list of files that have "word" in the filename?  If so, drop the `-l` and `*.csv` from your command

Comment: I tried `aws s3 ls  s3://path/folder/ | grep 'word'` but nothing was displayed.

Comment: Are you trying to list all objects that have "word" in their key, or all objects that contain "word" in their data?

Comment: All objects "CSVs" that contain "word" in their data.

Comment: Then you need to sync down the data and search it locally, or alternatively, you can use a tool like AWS Athena to search CSV files using SQL like queries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't have enough storage on my local machine to copy them all over. I have not tried AWS Athena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear that I will be able to search inside of CSVs "objects" inside of AWS s3. I would need to use a service like AWS Athena in order to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep -rn --include=*.csv "word"
```

or:

```
grep word *.csv
```

Comment: I spoke too soon. It is returning the files on my server, not the files on the s3 server. How do I limit it to just s3 files? This is what I am using. `aws s3 ls  s3://path/folder/ | grep -rn --include=*.csv 'word'`

Comment: This is what I got when I ran your last command. `download failed: s3://path/folder/ to - An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found`

Comment: @user3062459 are you sure your path is correct?

Comment: Yes. When I run `aws s3 ls  s3://path/folder/` I see all the CSV files.

Comment: Do you know of a way to grep file between a specfic date range? This way I can limit the number of files it looks at?

Comment: For it not grabbing your S3 server, I would probably start a new question, I do not think that is related to ```grep```. As for grepping a specific date range, at the top of my head I can only think of this ```grep '^\[2014-10-0[6-8]' file```. But you are trying to find files modified between specific date range?

Comment: In that case then awk would be better. ```aws s3 ls --recursive s3:// <your s3 path here> | awk '$1 > "2018-10-13 00:00:00" {print $0}' | sort -n``` for specific date. whats even better is just using the aws s3 api here is the code for finding range : ```aws s3api list-objects-v2 --max-items 10 --bucket "BUCKET" --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2019-10-01 00:00:00'] | [?LastModified<='2019-10-30 00:00:00'].{ Key: Key, Size: Size, LastModified: LastModified }"```

Comment: I appreciate your help.